# Pandas: remove group from the data when a value in the group contains similar value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["A", "A", "B" ,"B", "C", "C"],
                   "nickname":["X","Y","X","Z","Y", "Y"]})
```

How can I group df by "name" and drop those groups that contains only 'Y'?
In my case 'C' should be dropped.

I am using below code but it is not working:

```
df_new = df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: all(x['nickname'] != 'Y'))
```

In case, Y occurs in any other 'name' with some other nickname then that name should be retained. Kindly help.

Comment: "In case, Y occurs in any other 'name' with some other nickname then that name should be retained. ", ...so, how does the answer change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `groupby` is not necessary. You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['name'].isin(df.loc[df['nickname'].ne('Y'), 'name'].unique())]
print (df)
  name nickname
0    A        X
1    A        Y
2    B        X
3    B        Z
```

Explanation:

First compare by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) for not equal values:

```
print (df['nickname'].ne('Y'))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: nickname, dtype: bool
```

Then select column `name` bu boolean mask:

```
print (df.loc[df['nickname'].ne('Y'), 'name'])
0    A
2    B
3    B
Name: name, dtype: object
```

For better performance get unique values:

```
print(df.loc[df['nickname'].ne('Y'), 'name'].unique())
['A' 'B']
```

And filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for final mask:

```
print (df['name'].isin(df.loc[df['nickname'].ne('Y'), 'name'].unique()))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: name, dtype: bool
```

**Performance**:

Depends of number of rows, number of unique groups and number of matched values - best test in your real data:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100000

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.random.randint(1000,size=N).astype(str),
                   'nickname':np.random.randint(200,size=N).astype(str)})
#print (df)

In [152]: %timeit df[df.nickname.ne('Y').groupby(df.name).transform('sum').astype(bool)]
27.6 ms ± 292 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [153]: %timeit df[~df.nickname.eq('Y').groupby(df.name).transform('all')]
27.3 ms ± 162 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [154]: %timeit df[df['name'].isin(df.loc[df['nickname'].ne('Y'), 'name'].unique())]
28.9 ms ± 189 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [155]: %timeit df[~df.assign(mask=df.nickname.eq('Y')).groupby('name').mask.transform('all')]
30.3 ms ± 469 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [156]: %timeit df[df.groupby('name')['nickname'].transform('unique').astype(str) !="['Y']"]
15.6 s ± 233 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [157]: %timeit df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: any(x['nickname'] != 'Y'))
408 ms ± 29.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: In case, Y occurs in any other group with some other nickname then that name should be retained.

Comment: @AnkitaPatnaik - Yes, I agree, my solution working. Maybe help explanation for better understanding it.

Comment: Your answer is misleading: "Here groupby is not necessary, because slow in large data." is not true, try testing our solutions, the difference isn't that great. You're doing multiple passes on the data with `isin` and `unique`, your solution isn't that much faster either.

Comment: @coldspeed - OK, you know what I mean, be free change it.

Comment: Just telling you what you've told me, so many times before... "if man says their solution is faster, best is to time it, or let the OP do it."

Comment: @coldspeed  in my sample data it is same, so best test in real data :)

Comment: @coldspeed - check first test

Comment: Hi...in case i want to remove the first 'name' only if its 'nickname' is 'Y' then how can i do that? In above example, first 'Y' occurring in every group should be removed.

Comment: @AnkitaPatnaik - So if `df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["A", "A", "B" ,"B", "C", "C", "D",'D'],
                   "nickname":["X","Y","X","Z","Y", "Y",'Y','Z']})` what is expected output?

Comment: It should be:  name nickname
0    A        X
1    A        Y
2    B        X
3    B        Z
4    C        Y
5    D        Z

First occurence of Y in each group should be removed.

Comment: @AnkitaPatnaik - Can you check `df = df[df.duplicated('name') | df['nickname'].ne('Y')]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `groupby` and `transform`, or some derivative of the same thing.

```
df[~df.nickname.eq('Y').groupby(df.name).transform('all')]
# Or,
# df[~df.assign(mask=df.nickname.eq('Y')).groupby('name').mask.transform('all')]

  name nickname
0    A        X
1    A        Y
2    B        X
3    B        Z
```

---

An even faster `groupby`-related solution involves... counting!

```
df[df.nickname.ne('Y').groupby(df.name).transform('sum').astype(bool)]

  name nickname
0    A        X
1    A        Y
2    B        X
3    B        Z
```

Comment: Hi...in case i want to remove the first 'name' only if its 'nickname' is 'Y' then how can i do that? In above example, first 'Y' occurring in every group should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

simply use this,

```
temp= df.groupby('name')['nickname'].transform('unique').astype(str)
df=df[temp!="['Y']"]
print df
```

O/P

```
  name nickname
0    A        X
1    A        Y
2    B        X
3    B        Z
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe you needed in your solution `any` instead of `all`:

```
df_new = df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: any(x['nickname'] != 'Y'))
```

Output:

```
  name nickname
0    A        X
1    A        Y
2    B        X
3    B        Z
```

Comment: Hi...in case i want to remove the first 'name' only if its 'nickname' is 'Y' then how can i do that? In above example, first 'Y' occurring in every group should be removed.