# Remove all rows with specific ID if other column condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop, isin

I have a dataframe:

| id | country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | usa |
| 1 | mex |
| 1 | de |
| 2 | br |
| 2 | mex |
| 3 | usa |

I want to remove all Ids that country == usa

Desired output:

| id | country |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | br |
| 2 | mex |

Comment: [groupby filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html) -> `df.groupby('id').filter(lambda s: ~s['country'].eq('usa').any())` (Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38045266/15497888))

Comment: [groupby transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) -> `df[~df['country'].eq('usa').groupby(df['id']).transform('any')]` (Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53629767/15497888))